# Null value in the result of a left outer join linq causes error

Tags: c#, linq

I have linq query, that left outer join two tables. I found if a value of a field returns null,, then I will get an error message:

"The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

I copied my linq below:

```
var SrvRef = from s in db.SrvHeads
    join r in db.Referrants on s.svhReferrer equals r.refID into r_join
    from r in r_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where s.svhAccID == accId &&
    s.svhHeadCnt == HeadId
    select new
    {
    s.svhBalance,
    r.refID
    };
bool FBeenPaid = SrvRef.FirstOrDefault().svhBalance == 0M; //this causes error
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue.

**Cause:** You are using from "**r**" in `r_join.DefaultIfEmpty()`. You cannot use same alias name for left outer join.

**Solution:** Use different alias name if `DefaultIfEmpty()` cases. Eg: `rEmpty`
I modified the below query and its working.

```
var SrvRef = from s in db.SrvHeads
join r in db.Referrants on s.svhReferrer equals r.refID into r_join
from rEmpty in r_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
where s.svhAccID == accId &&
s.svhHeadCnt == HeadId
select new
{
s.svhBalance,
refID = rEmpty == null ? 0 : rEmpty.refID
};
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm slightly surprised at the kind of error you're getting, but there are *two* places you need to take account of the possibility of the result being null:

- Within the query, where `r` can be null. (If you don't want to match when there are no elements in `r_join` matching `s`, you shouldn't be using a left outer join)
- In the result itself: you're using `FirstOrDefault()` which will return `null` if `SrvRef` is empty.

So at first glance it should probably be something like:

```
var query = from s in db.SrvHeads
    join r in db.Referrants on s.svhReferrer equals r.refID into r_join
    from r in r_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where s.svhAccID == accId && s.svhHeadCnt == HeadId
    select new
    {
        s.svhBalance,
        refId = r == null ? 0 : r.refID // Adjust to the appropriate type of refID
    };
var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
bool beenPaid = result != null && result.svhBalance == 0m;
```

With C# 6, you can change the bottom two lines to:

```
bool beenPaid = query.FirstOrDefault()?.svhBalance == 0m ?? false;
```

Having said that:

- You're not currently using `refId` in the result anyway - why are you including it in the result?
- Are you sure you want a left outer join at all?
- Are you sure that taking the *first* result is really what you want? What if there are multiple results in the join?
- Is there any reason you're not doing the whole thing in a query? Something like:

  ```
  var paid = db.SrvHeads
               .Where(s => s.svhAccID == accId && s.svhHeadCnt == HeadId)
               .Any(s => db.Refererrants.Any(r => s.svhReferrer == r.refID
                       && s.svhBalance == 0m);
  ```

  .. but just for the precise semantics you want.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help. I really need the left outer join. and I need the refId and use it later. I only need the first row, and actually there should only have one row. When I hover the mouse over the SrvRef, I got the sql statement, I run the sql in the sql management studio, it returns a result with refId = null. so the sql has no trouble. If I remove the refId from linq, there is no problem as well. so the problem is cause by a null value field in the select clause.

Comment: @peter: It's not `r.refId` that's null here, it's `r` - which is why extracting `r.refId` fails. That's what my code takes account of.

Answer (score 1):

what i think is causing an error is that svhBalance is an int32 value type and you are accessing a null value returned by SrvRef.FirstOrDefault(). 
please try the following line and let me know if it helped you.

**if svhBalance is an int value type**

> *var SrvRefObj= SrvRef.FirstOrDefault(); bool FBeenPaid = (((SrvRefObj!=null)&&(SrvRefObj.svhBalance
>   !=null))?(SrvRefObj.svhBalance == 0):(false))*

**else if it's a decimal value type**

> *var SrvRefObj= SrvRef.FirstOrDefault(); bool FBeenPaid = (((SrvRefObj!=null)&&(SrvRefObj.svhBalance
>   !=null))?(SrvRefObj.svhBalance == 0M):(false))*

Comment: Thank you for your help. the problem happens when the linq returns result.

Comment: Thanks Peter for responding. If you think it solved your problem then please mark it as Answered. 
Regards